# Multiple views same model[MVC 3]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have one  model and one controller  for multiple views.
The model have some required fields but for a specific view i need to ignore the validation for 2 specific fields.
There is any method to ignore the validation for those 2 fields?

I am using asp.net MVC3.

Model code example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campul strada este obligatoriu")]
    public string Strada { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Numar strada")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campul strada numar este obligatoriu")]
public string NrStrada { get; set; }
```

For 9/10 views that is ok but for 1 view i don't want to be requiered.

Comment: Please be more specific! Which programming language, which framework/libraries are you using? Think about providing some example code. People can only help you as good as you ask.

Comment: You should look into using ViewModels instead.  Post some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: For that one view, rather than using Html.EditorFor/Html.TextBoxFor, you can use try using the Html.TextBox helper, i don't think that outputs the tags that are needed for html validation, so you should get through client side validation with that.  server side, you will need to check the modelstate and remove the errors for those two fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When such an issue occurs then I normally create different view models.  Each with it's own validation logic.  There's nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Here are examples, not relating to your code, you can adjust your code accordingly.

For example with create customer I would have a create customer view model, and for edit customer I would have a edit customer view model.  Each has different sets of validation.  Create customer only requirs a first name and a last name.  Edit customer needs a first name, last name, and employee number of who updated the customer record.  Employee number updater is not required when adding a new customer.

Here is a possible create customer view model:

```
public class CreateCustomerViewModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a possible edit customer view model:

```
public class EditCustomerViewModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
     public string UpdatedByEmployeeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is just a basic example.

Comment: while implementing the unobtrusive client validation, we can ignore some of them